# How to create a dict like class in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Looks like there are multiple ways to do that but couldn't find the latest best method.

1. Subclass UserDict
2. Subclass DictMixin
3. Subclass dict
4. Subclass MutableMapping

What is the correct way to do? I want to abstract actual data which is in a database.

Comment: 5. Implement mapping methods

Answer (score 0):

Since your dict-like class isn't in fact a dictionary, I'd go with `MutableMapping`. Subclassing `dict` implies dict-like characteristics, including performance characteristics, which won't be true if you're actually hitting a database.

Comment: Can you point to some example? What exactly should be customized?

Comment: ... whatever you need to customize?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing your own thing (e.g. inventing your own wheel) you might as well write the class from scratch (i.e. subclass from `object`), just providing the correct special members (e.g. `__getitem__`) and other such functions as described in the object [data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), so that it quacks like a dict. Internally, you might even own a number of dicts (has-a) to help your implementation.

This way, you don't have to shoehorn your design to "fit" some existing implementation, and you aren't paying for some things you aren't necessarily using .This recommendation in part is because your DB-backed class will already be considerably more complex than a standard dict if you make it account for performance/caching/consistency/optimal querying etc.